# .ipa size is larger than overall project size

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

My overall project size is 29.9MB but when I archive it, `.ipa` size is 49.4MB. I am not using any third-party sdks in the application.

What could be the reason for this increase in `.ipa` size?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question, but I'll play along for a bit: do you have lots of high resolution graphics?  are you building for every possible architecture (armv7, armv7s, arm64, etc.)?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i used images for iphone & ipad screens, and ya i am building with 3 architectures that you mention in your comment.

Comment: in build settings : i set standard architectures for Architectures option. and for valid architectures : i used above 3 architectures.

Comment: Are you using some kind of source controller like git or TFS ???

Comment: as of now, because of ipa size issue i removed git folder from my project directory.

Comment: It might be just a universal binary you build for, though twice the size is a little bit much, I guess your resources take up the major part of your project size-wise.

Comment: @ff10, sorry but i dont think that the problem is related to universal binary, and ya when i set to NO to Compress PNG Files (in build settings) then ipa size is 28MB , so the problem related to my images

Answer (score 0):

IPA is just a .zip file (you can rename it as .zip and see what's inside, you can see if there are files that should not be in).

Comment: thanks.. i already check that.. using show package contents.. but didnt find anything unused files from it.

Comment: And the size of the files ? anything stands out ?

Comment: i check that also, problem is related to images, because may be my images are converted from jpg to png just by changing its extension. i am looking on it

Comment: ha Sulea, sorry for late reply. i have a .png file having 11MB size, after creating ipa and show its package contents.. the same file size getting 19MB :(, so what wud be the reason for 11MB to 19MB ?

Comment: well ... that is strange for sure, you can try to make a binary compare between the two files and maybe you can see where that additional size is from (I don't know if png has quality settings or if something changes the image size while making the ipa)

Comment: ya its really a strange issue, i just compare a one file having 11 MB (only a .png file) in my project directory, after making its ipa, that same file have 19MB size. even i am not able to understand why xcode increases the size of the images, in xcode->build settings -> i set png compress = YES.

Comment: well ... most likely the compression algorithm fails in that case :-)